# Breeze jsonresultsadapter inject data properties while traversing nodes

Tags: breeze

I would like to add data properties for child nodes that have been predefined in nav properties of my metadata that I am created by hand as my model. These new data properties will be used to establish the relationship between the parent and child node.

## How to do it:

Basically what I want to do is create the new data property of a node that is deemed the child node with the id of the parent node. I am thinking this would be done under the visitNode code within my jsonResultsAdapter code.

## Question:

Once the new child data property has been added will this established the relationship between the parent and child nodes. Can I then create breeze queries against this?

Has anyone done this before and if so please share.

Thanks anyone for your feedback, this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your *JsonResultsAdapter* create a property that did not exist in the incoming feed, but Breeze will need to have metadata for this property already specified. i.e you need to update the Breeze *EntityType* metadata ( see Breeze docs) to contain any properties that you plan to add dynamically in your JsonRe*emphasized text*sultsAdapter.

You will NOT be able to create queries against such properties, however, because Breeze has no idea how to compose such queries.